# Correct way of Caching and this when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, caching

When using jQuery, caching is very important, and it seems I have forgotten the related principals. When I cache something, how can I re-use it inside function `on()`?

Example:

```
var paginationDemo = $("#pagination-demo");
paginationDemo.on('click', function() {
  var index = $('#pagination-demo').find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML;
  ...
});
```

As you can see here, I am calling jQuery again to find the id, shame on me! Is there a way to do it with `this`?

```
var index = this.find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML;
```

or:

```
var index = $(this).find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML;
```

But I am not sure what will `this` hold inside the body of `on()`. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: this is the DOM object, $(this) is the jQuery object so this.id and $(this).find - but why not `$(this).find('.active > a').html();` ?

Comment: So what will be `this` inside the body of the unnamed function ( how do we call these function? :) )? It will will the `paginationDemo` variable, intuitionally? So you mean `this.id.find()` will be equivalently with `$(this).find()`.

Comment: No. this.id and $(this).attr("id)" are equivalent. ignore the example with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of variable caching just reuse the variable "paginationDemo"  again inside 'on'. The second approach also works fine in this case.

```
var index = $(this).find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML;
```

Because 'this' still holds the reference to DOM object.

But this approach looses its validity inside nested functions or anonymous functions (the 'unnamed' functions). So you can save the reference to this variable to make is work (the self approach). Or use the cached variable directly (paginationDemo).  eg below:

```
 var paginationDemo = $("#paginationDemo");
    paginationDemo.on('click', function(e) {
          var self =this;      // saving reference to this
          console.log(this);     // refers to DOM object paginationDemo

          var index = $(this).find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML; 
                                 //will work
          var index = paginationDemo.find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML; 
                                    //will work, this is caching approach

         (function (){
              //inside anonymous fun, this changed now
            console.log(this);      // this refers to "window" object now!
            var index = $(this).find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML; //won't work

            var index = $(self).find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML; 
                               //works !! lexical scope variable self used    

            paginationDemo.find('.to-be-found').text('FOUND');
                                 //works too

       })();
    });
```

Here is a link to how this works  :
[this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Promil thanks! I was thinking about this approach as well..Maybe I have to refresh variable scope when dealing with functions...I mean how on earth does the anonymous function knows about `self`? You declared it as `var self`, thus it's not global...But I believe you!

Comment: @gsamaras  Welcome :)  Javascript uses lexical scoping. ( function level scope) So the the inner anonymous function has access to variables of the parent (i.e. variable self ) and also to global object variables (window in most cases).  just self = this;  ( without var) would have made it global variable.

Comment: So what happens with self in the anonymous function, is the same thing as what happens with the `paginationDemo`, right? :) I learned a lot from this question, but it ruined by positive score, and I didn't get the Socratic badge! :/

Comment: Haha... Yes both of them are global and remain unchanged here. 'this' is a very special js variable and its value inside a function depends on who is calling that function. ( each function gets it own this. read it in detail. very awesome concept it is ! )

Comment: Also starting from ECMA 6 I beleive, we can use the "fat arrow functions" which pick up the value of 'this' on the basis of block where it is defined, not the object which calls that function. So no need to assign self = this in the future :)  http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Your second option will work:

```
var index = $(this).find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't want just this to work, I want to understand. See the comment discussion under my question and try to expand your answer, explaining why this would be the correct way and such, please. :)

Comment: Without the `$()`, `this` is DOM object, and not a jquery object, and DOM objects dont have the `find` method

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to use the jquery object that you created inside the call-back you registered via `on` as well.

From the [official docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/) :

> In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has
>   access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the
>   keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can
>   use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )`

But in this case as well you will have to construct the jQuery object again. Not as costly as using a selector to find an element but none the less.

One solution to the problem might be to use the `event.data` property

```
var paginationDemo = $("#pagination-demo");
paginationDemo.on('click',{ cachedElement:paginationDemo},function(event) {
  var index = event.data.cachedElement.find('.active > a')[0].innerHTML;
  ...
});
```

This way you can reuse the original jQuery object and acheive what you wanted from cacheing.

UPDATE :

Inside the call-back passed to `on`,  the key word `this` refers to the underlying DOM object. When we use this idiom : `$(this)` we are constructing a fresh jQuery object. However it is not the same as the jQuery object stored in `paginationDemo` variable. In other words both the jQuery objects will act on the same **DOM element**. However their references are different

```
event.data.cachedElement === $(this)
>false
```

Comment: Nice approach too, +1! But what is the difference between this approach and `this`? Are they equivalent?

Comment: this keyword  inside the call-back actually refers to the underlying DOM object. Now if we do $(this), we are basically wrapping the DOM object inside a jQuery object. however the jQuery object is created anew. that it is not a reference to the object stored in paginationDemo. In other words, both paginationDemo and $(this) would act on the same DOM element but are infact different objects.

Comment: I do not see the necessity of your code. This should work too: `var $paginationDemo = $("#pagination-demo");
$paginationDemo.on('click',function() {
  var index = $(this).find('.active > a').text(); });` assuming `<a class="active">10</a>' - where does the documentation say that $(this) is a new copy?

Comment: Like I said in the answer the general idiom is to use $(this).... I was just suggesting an alternative that came to my mind :)